# Поменяйте местами min и max

Tags: python, python-3.x

В списке все элементы различны. Поменяйте местами минимальный и максимальный элемент этого списка.

PS Сделать надо максимально просто

PSS не так :

```
a = [int(s) for s in input().split()]
index_of_min = 0
index_of_max = 0
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    if a[i] > a[index_of_max]:
        index_of_max = i
    if a[i] < a[index_of_min]:
        index_of_min = i
a[index_of_min], a[index_of_max] = a[index_of_max], a[index_of_min]
print(' '.join([str(i) for i in a]))
```

И не так

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
min_index = a.index(min(a))
max_index = a.index(max(a))
[a[max_index], a[min_index]] = [a[min_index], a[max_index]]
print(' '.join([str(i) for i in a]))
```

Comment: А куда проще способа 1. Чем он сложен?

Comment: Вопрос следует закрыть, т.к. совершенно не понятно, какими возможностями языка можно пользоваться, а какими нельзя, и на попытки помочь автор минусует ответы.

Answer (score 2):

Вы бы хоть сказали, чем вам функции не угодили, особенно первая. Почему "не так"?
И что в вашем понимании "простое решение"?

Ну вот вам более "простое" решение (впрочем, я в этом не уверен, но вдруг вам оно таким покажется?)

```
a = [int(s) for s in input().split()]    
a[a.index(max(a))], a[a.index(min(a))] = a[a.index(min(a))], a[a.index(max(a))]
```

Comment: Мы этого просто не проходили и понять этого не могу как и твой ответ...

Answer (score 2):

Существует эффективный алгоритм поиска максимума и минимума. Если под простотой понимается эффективность.

Разобьем все элементы на пары, и будем искать в каждой паре минимум и максимум (n/2 сравнений), затем минимум будем искать только среди минимальных элементов пар, а максимум - среди максимальных. Общее количество сравнений будет около 3n/2 (проблема возникает, когда количество элементов нечетное - один из элементов остается без пары).

```
a = [int(s) for s in input().split()]
if a[0]>a[1]:
    index_of_min = 1
    index_of_max = 0
else:
    index_of_min = 0
    index_of_max = 1
for i in range(2, len(a)-1,2):
    if a[i] > a[i+1]:
        if a[i+1]<a[index_of_min]:
            index_of_min=i+1
        if a[i]>a[index_of_max]:
            index_of_max=i
    else:
        if a[i]<a[index_of_min]:
            index_of_min=i
        if a[i+1]>a[index_of_max]:
            index_of_max=i+1
if len(a) % 2==1:
    if a[len(a)-1]<a[index_of_min]:
            index_of_min=len(a)-1
    if a[len(a)-1]>a[index_of_max]:
            index_of_max=len(a)-1

print(a[index_of_max], a[index_of_min])
c=a[index_of_max]
a[index_of_max]=a[index_of_min]
a[index_of_min]=c
print(a)
```

Comment: Я уже решил задачу, и зачем так тяжело?

Comment: Можно же так :                                                                                                                                  
`MX[MX.index(min(MX))], MX[ma = MX.index(max(MX))] = MX[ma = MX.index(max(MX))], MX[mi = MX.index(min(MX))]`

Comment: Можно по разному. Я привел пример более эффективного алгоритма, чем ваш.